# How can I have different groups of editors only allowed to edit certain parent+subpages?

Tags: user-roles, capabilities, user-access, permissions

I've tried a bunch of different plugins, including Role Scoper, Advanced Access Manager, User Account Manager and more, to accomplish this but can't seem to get it working right.

Basically, the company has multiple departments and each department has a parent page + sub pages off the 'Main Page'. For example, the 'conference services' department has a page called 'conference services' and several child pages.

I need to be able to create a group of users who are 'conference services editors' and when they go to pages they should only see the parent page 'conference services' and any subpages. (as well, they should only see posts under the category 'conference services')

Is this possible with one install?

Thanks,
Thomas

Comment: Can you explain *how* did you tried to implement this plugins? You don't mention if this is supposed to happen in the back or the front end. Check this [search results](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Bpre_get_posts+%2Brole).

Comment: Pretty sure you _can_ do this with Role Scoper, but admittedly that isn't the most intuitive or friendliest of plugins.

Comment: @vancoder correct - you can do it, but it's not the friendliest plugin. I've figured it out - but it's not exactly intuitive, finally working though.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE - this is easy to do with the press permit plugin, I recommend it for any setup like this**

To get this working I had to do a couple of things:

1. Default all pages/posts/categories 'revisor' (via Revisionary plugin) users to be restricted to 'WP_Administrators'
2. Create a "User Group" for each department ie: 'Conference Services Revisors'.
3. When the parent page for a department is created change the 'Revisors' restriction on pages/posts/categories from 'WP_Administrators' to the User Group of that department ie: 'Conference Services Revisors' and selecte 'All pages/subpages'/'categories/sub categories' etc
4. Add all revisor users from each department to their respective User Group

So far this seems to be working as intended. Conference Services users only see/have access to conference services parent page and sub pages - as well as posts and all of the custom post types I've created as well.

The only issue I have now is that when adding new pages, either because their revisors or because of the restrictions they can't select a parent page - this is not a huge issue it just means that when an admin is reviewing the new page before publishing they have to remember to add the parent page of the proper department.

And a similar issue with posts, when they add a new post they have the ability to selected any categories they want to attach to the post even though I've restricted them to only their parent/child categories (restricted for seeing/editing posts but not assigning the categories to new posts). The potential problem with this is that they can select 'featured news' which would put their story onto the main page when maybe it shouldn't be or into any other departments feeds as well. Again, because of the revisionary plugin this is not a huge issue as long as administrators remember to ensure only correct categories are selected before publishing.